# PHP SVN - branch/tag functionality

Tags: php, svn

I am trying to replicate (using PHP SVN libraries) the same copy functionality that is used on tortoise (for example) when creating a new branch from the trunk. At the end is a simple copy from trunk to branches.

For this I found the following function [svn_fs_copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.svn-fs-copy.php)

The problem I have is that I don't see any way to enter a comment when this action is executed so it can be correctly tracked when checking the svn log...

Does anyone know how I could achieve the same branch/tag functionality with the extra of adding a comment into the log?

Or does this look like I should have to do it manually (fodler creation + add + commit)?

Comment: Is anyone familiar with this usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the info I was needing on here

http://blog.danguer.com/2011/10/05/recipes-for-using-svn-library-in-php/